# python replacing occurrence of one variable in incrementing order while the other in decrementing order

Tags: python, shell

```
var0 = {p,q};
var1 = {p,q};
var2 = {p,q};
var3 = {p,q};
.
.
.
var63 = {p,q};
```

need the above code changed to:

```
var0 = {63,0};
var1 = {62,1};
var2 = {61,2};
var3 = {60.3};
.
.
.
var63 = {0,63};
```

need the occurrence of p to decrement and occurrence of q to increment.

Comment: Yes. What's the problem? Do you know how to increment a number? Do you know how to decrement a number? Do you know how to make a loop from 0 to 63? And why would one declare 64 variables like that in the first place instead of using a) a calculation or b) an array? This sounds like an [xy-problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: No I don't I am just starting myself to python.. I am not able to accomplish this task.. I need to know what regex or methods we can use to do this.

Comment: Then, please take a Python tutorial and come back when you know the fundamentals.

Comment: thanks will do parallelly doing these small codes too... So I learn while doing the course... really appreciate your suggestion...

Comment: I tried something which work.. but I feel it can be done.. more elegant way


```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "0214 script begins"
i=0
file = open ('file0.sv','r')
for line in file:
  i = i+1
  num1 = (((i+1)/2)-1)
  num2 = 63 - num1
  c_num1 = str(num1)
  c_num2 = str(num2)
  line = line.replace('q',c_num1)
  line = line.replace('p',c_num2)
  write_file = open("file1.sv","a")
  write_file.write(line)
  write_file.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: That code is hard to read in a comment. You can [edit] the question and have some proper formatting there. But yeah, all the statements are basically there: increment, decrement, opening file, closing file, replacing, ...